# Shutdown Hook in Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-isolates

I need make some action (dump statistical data) before the Dart program ends. The program continues after the method main ends (there are other isolates), so I cannot determine exactly the moment when the program finishes.

In Java, I can use java.lang.Runtime.addShutdownHook. Does similar feature exist in the Dart runtime?

Comment: For clarification, your program runs "forever" until you kill it, and at that point your want to dump some statistical data?  One option for now would be to periodically dump the statistical data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't, at least not directly in Dart. If you embed Dart VM into your program, you can register such hook for any isolate via the embedding API.

In the future, there will probably be some kind of isolates monitoring (which is useful in a lot of scenarios), so that you can get notified when an isolate dies (either normally or by an uncaught exception), but it isn't there now.

Answer (score 0):

There was support for this added a while ago

see https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=15188